# Codeigniter image resize not work properly

Tags: codeigniter

I want to resize the uploaded image as the ratio of 400 x 350. I use below code for this.

```
$config = array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image'      => $img_data['full_path'],
        'new_image'         => $this->upload_path. '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ration'   => FALSE,
        'width'             => 350,
        'height'            => 400
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Codeigniter give me the image as the ratio of 400 x 340.

Comment: Do you have the dependencies installed? GD/GD2, NetPBM, or ImageMagick

Comment: Can you keep these two options $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE; Since the maintain_ratio option is enabled, the thumb will be as close to the target width and height as possible while preserving the original aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks Venkat. I try it like you said but it still 400x340.

Comment: can you update your new code after you changed those options

Comment: I change my code like below.$config = array(
   'image_library' => 'gd2',
   'source_image'   => $img_data['full_path'],
   'new_image'      => $this->upload_path. '/thumbs',
   'create_thumb'   => TRUE,
   'maintain_ration' => TRUE,
   'width'    => 350,
   'height'   => 400
  );
   
  $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
  $this->image_lib->resize();

Answer (score 0):

see if this could help.
Here is the link to the class required to accomplish the task you looking for

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/